# Save/open Office files from/to OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

I have Office 2016 installed on Windows 10 PC build .1703. And on that Windows 10 PC I only selected 2 OneDrive folders to synchronize locally.

Now I open any office application I try to save it to a folder not locally synchronized yet
[image]

No matter what I do, it always just browse local OneDrive folder instead of full OneDrive online structure.

Same thing happens if I try to open from a OneDrive folder not locally synchronized.

Any idea what can I do? I don't really want to synchronize everything from OneDrive.

Comment: "open from a OneDrive folder not locally synchronized" - You need to better describe what you mean by this.  In your screenshot the Save As dialog is filtering out any file that isn't a .pptx file.

Comment: When I set up OneDrive initially I was prompted which folders are to be synchronized, so any changes to these folders locally will be synchronized to OneDrive automatically. But I did not choose entire OneDrive, instead I only chose 2 folders in OneDrive. There are more folders from OneDrive. I want to save files to these folders not visible locally yet.

Comment: Are you using 1703 or 1709?  **Edit** your question and clarify it.

Comment: Edited, it is 1703.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what your question is. What build of Office 2016 are you using?  I am using 1709 and the save as dialog doesn't look like the dialog in your screenshot.  You are logged into your MS account, within Office, right?

Comment: The dialog box only shows the folders which are synchronized locally (I ever picked them in OneDrive app). I want to be able to see all folders in OneDrive.

Comment: I asked you for some additional information.  I cannot answer your question until you provide it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t appear the you are browsing your online OneDrive account. This is evidenced by the fact that file explorer is clearly showing a local folder.

If you are only looking at the local folder you’re not going to see the online files. As you stated, you aren’t syncing the files you are looking for locally.

Be sure you are signed in to Office, and OneDrive will work online automatically. Files are opened and saved directly from OneDrive online.

See here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-OneDrive-with-Office-b1c976de-ef52-4d53-950f-d48f2c6427df

As seen in the article, if you have disabled the option to “Use Office to work on files with other people at the same time,” it will also cause Office to revert to using local folders only in my experience.

As a final step, if this hasn’t gotten you in the right track, make sure you have installed the latest version of OneDrive. There have been massive changes, like the next gen. unified client, and it is quite likely you’re running an obsolete version.

http://onedrive.live.com

Comment: I signed in to my Microsoft ID in Office, I did as what the document mentioned "Open the document you want to save to OneDrive, tap or click File > Save As, choose your OneDrive, and then choose the folder where you want to save the file." But I only can see 2 folders synchronized locally. And I do believe I have all apps up to date.